# Wordpress Installation : Sorry, but I can’t write the wp-config.php file

Tags: php, wordpress, xampp, xampp-vm

I get the following issue when trying to install Wordpress on xampp-vm on macOS Catalina.  The only option they suggest is that:

`You can create the wp-config.php file manually and paste the following text into it.`

xampp creates a virtual machine in xampp-vm now. So how to enable write permissions to xampp-vm by Wrdpress? Im running xampp locally.

Comment: https://kinsta.com/knowledgebase/installation-failed-could-not-create-directory/

Comment: Give read and write permissions to wp-config.php